# Parsing a new line separated string when whitespace is included

Tags: python, parsing

I am using the really neat [Parsy](https://parsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) library to split a string (as part of a bigger grammar definition.) The sep_by works great when there are no embedded spaces. Basically I want to split by new line and get all the characters including embedded spaces or any other Unicode character. Examples:

works:

```
>>> parser = letter.at_least(1).concat().sep_by(string('\n'))
>>> parser.parse('Smith\nFirefighter')
['Smith', 'Firefighter']
```

doesn't work:

```
>>> parser.parse('John Smith\nFire fighter')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\code\Parsing\Parsing\env\lib\site-packages\parsy\__init__.py", line 90, in parse
    (result, _) = (self << eof).parse_partial(stream)
  File "C:\code\Parsing\Parsing\env\lib\site-packages\parsy\__init__.py", line 104, in parse_partial
    raise ParseError(result.expected, stream, result.furthest)
parsy.ParseError: expected one of 'EOF', '\n', 'a letter' at 0:4
```

I would also like to read in any embedded Unicode character like this chess symbol:

```
>>> parser.parse('hello\u265ethere\nsir')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\code\Parsing\Parsing\env\lib\site-packages\parsy\__init__.py", line 90, in parse
    (result, _) = (self << eof).parse_partial(stream)
  File "C:\code\Parsing\Parsing\env\lib\site-packages\parsy\__init__.py", line 104, in parse_partial
    raise ParseError(result.expected, stream, result.furthest)
parsy.ParseError: expected one of 'EOF', '\n', 'a letter' at 0:5
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. Also can somebody with a larger reputation create a parsy tag maybe?

Comment: Out of curiosity is there a reason you don't use the built in `.split()` method? and just do `myStr.split('\n')`

Comment: [`parsy.letter`](https://parsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/primitives.html#parsy.letter) only accepts letters, hence the failure. Try building a custom [`Parser`](https://parsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/primitives.html#parsing-primitives) instead.

Comment: Error - I am not doing split because this is a parser grammar being executed in sequence, basically on the 'next segment'

Comment: Brian - Right you are! letter is defined to be ascii chars only.
I got it working by doing
`allow = (letter | whitespace)
parser = allow.at_least(1).concat().sep_by(string('\n'))`
Please post separate answer, I will mark it as answered. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Paul for adding the parsy tag

Comment: Had posted too soon. (letter | whitespace) alone didn't work. See my solution and @spookylukey even better parsy-ish solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with solutions so far:

- `letter` only matches alphabetical characters, not all characters
- `whitespace` matches any whitespace, so if you do `letter | whitespace` it will consume the newline, instead of splitting on it.

Essentially you want an "any character but newline" parser. The easiest way to do that is with regex:

```
>>> parser = regex(r"[^\n]+").sep_by(string('\n'))
>>> parser.parse("John Smith\nFirefigher")
['John Smith', 'Firefigher']
```

I usually find with Parsy, regex is the easiest way to build the lowest level parts.

Comment: Thanks [spookylukey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182604/spookylukey). I got this working by doing `any_char.many().concat()` and slurping it via `yield` into a variable, THEN doing a python newline `split()` on it. Your solution of course is much better. Thank you!